# Retrieving iCloud documents on a fresh app install

Tags: ios, icloud

I have an app that works fine with iCloud - I can create, save and edit files with no problem.

The problem I'm having is with fresh installs of the app on other devices.  Since its a fresh install, the ubiquitous folder exists but does not have anything in it.  I would like to know how to search the **remote** iCloud folder for an newly-installed app that has the same account and file names as the original app that stored the document on the cloud.

I know there is this function:

```
[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous: itemAtURL:destinationURL: error:
```

And 'setUbiquitous' can be set to NO and the itemAtURL is the iCLoud remote URL and destinationURL is the filepath returned by [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil]

But how do I get the itemAtURL, which sounds like it would be a remote URL?  Or is this the wrong function to call?

UPDATE:  This is my query function

NSMetadataQuery *tmpQuery = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
    _query = tmpQuery;

```
[tmpQuery setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope, nil]];
NSPredicate *tmpPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, inDocName];
[tmpQuery setPredicate:tmpPred];

// we must add this so that we know when the query has completed
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryDidFinishGathering:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:_query];

static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(iCloudQueryDidUpdate:)
                                                 name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification
                                               object:_query];

});


[tmpQuery startQuery];
```

I think it may be the way I'm testing.  If I delete the app from my device, and then go into Settings > iCloud and delete the docs,  it seems like I'm deleting them from the iCloud server as well.  Could this be the case?

Comment: You have to use `NSMetadataQuery`. Do a search in the iOS docs for examples.

Comment: NSMetadataQuery *tmpQuery = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
    _query = tmpQuery;
    
    [tmpQuery setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope, nil]];
    NSPredicate *tmpPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, inDocName];
    [tmpQuery setPredicate:tmpPred];
    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryDidFinishGathering:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:_query];
[tmpQuery startQuery];

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, but thats what I"m using.  As far as I can tell, NSMetadataQuery can only be used for local searching

Comment: You can't stuff all of that code in a comment. Update your question with those details. And `NSMetadataQuery` is quite capable of searching iCloud.

Comment: @CaptainQuality that is incorrect, `NSMetadataQuery` works for finding documents in iCloud too. See, for example, `NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope`.